# Create custom square CheckBox control in .net MAUI MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mvvm, maui

This is the thing that drives me crazy!
I just can't find a way to create custom control for CheckBox component. I need Android and iOS working component to look like this when IsChecked = false/true.

[image: custom .net MAUI CheckBox control]

For RadioButton, it was fairly simple, but not for a CheckBox. I'm no expert in MAUI, and have "limited" knowledge in C#. But i did create a custom components like CustomDatePicker, CustomUnderlinedEntry, CustomRadioButton...

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlaNamespace"
         x:Class="BlaNamespace.YourPage"> 

<StackLayout>
    <local:SquareCheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" />
    <BoxView WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20" 
             BorderColor="Black" BorderThickness="1"
             BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyCheckBox}, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />
</StackLayout>
```

But i need functionality of CheckBox!

Comment: add a Tapped gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could "almost" just make a custom `Button` with an `IsChecked` property but the problem is how the border wants to draw in 3D. So one decent way to do this is to take a `Button`, remove its border entirely and put it inside a view (`_innerBorder`) that is inside of another view. This makes it very customizable in terms of border widths (inner and outer) which are now a function of the `Padding` and `Margin` values of the `_innerBorder`, and both width and height requests can now be set as using a new `Dimension` property that makes a square.

```xml
<!--Style Test-->
<local:CheckBoxEx
    x:Name="Styled1"
    Dimension="30"
    CheckedColor="Yellow"
    OuterBorderColor="Fuchsia"
    InnerBorderColor="Aqua"
    OuterBorderWidth="3"
    InnerBorderWidth="3"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    IsCheckedChanged="Any_CheckedChanged"
    IsChecked="True" />
```

[image: android and iPhone showing checkboxes]

```cs
public class CheckBoxEx : ContentView
{
    public CheckBoxEx()
    {
        BackgroundColor = OuterBorderColor;
        Padding = new Thickness(0);
        _impl = new Button
        {
            CornerRadius = 0,
            BorderWidth = 0,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
            Margin = new Thickness(0),
            Padding = new Thickness(0),
            BackgroundColor = UncheckedColor,
        };
        _innerBorder = new ContentView
        {
            Content = _impl,
            Padding = InnerBorderWidth,
            Margin = OuterBorderWidth,
            BackgroundColor = InnerBorderColor,
        };
        _impl.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (IsEnabled) IsChecked = !IsChecked;
        };
        Content = _innerBorder;
    }
    public event EventHandler IsCheckedChanged;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isChecked, value))
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                _impl.BackgroundColor = IsChecked ? CheckedColor : UncheckedColor; 
                IsCheckedChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isChecked = false;
    public Color CheckedColor
    {
        get => _checkedColor;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_checkedColor, value))
            {
                _checkedColor = value;
                if(IsChecked) _impl.BackgroundColor = CheckedColor;
            }
        }
    }
    Color _checkedColor = Colors.CornflowerBlue;

    public Color UncheckedColor
    {
        get => _uncheckedColor;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_uncheckedColor, value))
            {
                _uncheckedColor = value;
                if (!IsChecked) _impl.BackgroundColor = UncheckedColor;
            }
        }
    }
    Color _uncheckedColor = Colors.White;

    public Color OuterBorderColor
    {
        get => _outerBorderColor;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_outerBorderColor, value))
            {
                _outerBorderColor = value;
                BackgroundColor = OuterBorderColor;
            }
        }
    }
    Color _outerBorderColor = Colors.Black;
    public Color InnerBorderColor
    {
        get => _innerBorderColor;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_innerBorderColor, value))
            {
                _innerBorderColor = value;
                _innerBorder.BackgroundColor = InnerBorderColor;
            }
        }
    }
    Color _innerBorderColor = Colors.WhiteSmoke;


    public double Dimension
    {
        get => _dimension;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_dimension, value))
            {
                _dimension = value;
                HeightRequest = Dimension;
                WidthRequest = Dimension;
            }
        }
    }
    double _dimension = default;

    public int OuterBorderWidth
    {
        get => _outerBorderWidth;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_outerBorderWidth, value))
            {
                _outerBorderWidth = value;
                _innerBorder.Margin = OuterBorderWidth;
            }
        }
    }
    int _outerBorderWidth = 2;

    public int InnerBorderWidth
    {
        get => _innerBorderWidth;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_innerBorderWidth, value))
            {
                _innerBorderWidth = value;
                _innerBorder.Padding = InnerBorderWidth;
            }
        }
    }
    int _innerBorderWidth = 2;

    private readonly ContentView _innerBorder;
    private readonly Button _impl;
}
```

Comment: [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/check-box-with-inner-and-outer-borders.git)

Answer (score 0):

First you need create a new class for your custom CheckBox. This class should inherit from ContentView or another appropriate MAUI control.

```
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls;

namespace BlaNamespace
{
    public class CustomCheckBox : ContentView
    {
        private readonly BoxView checkBox;
    public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomCheckBox), false, propertyChanged: OnIsCheckedChanged);

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
        set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox()
    {
        checkBox = new BoxView
        {
            WidthRequest = 20,
            HeightRequest = 20,
            BorderColor = Color.Black,
            BorderThickness = 1
        };

        checkBox.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = new Command(() => IsChecked = !IsChecked)
        });

        Content = checkBox;
    }

    private static void OnIsCheckedChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var checkBox = (CustomCheckBox)bindable;
        checkBox.checkBox.BackgroundColor = (bool)newValue ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
    }
}
}
```

In your XAML file, you can now use your CustomCheckBox control.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlaNamespace"
         x:Class="BlaNamespace.YourPage">

<StackLayout>
    <local:CustomCheckBox x:Name="MyCheckBox" />
    <Label Text="My CheckBox" />
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, based on @Amardeep code, i was able to create something that worked for me.

EDIT: This ONLY worked on Android.

```
public class DinitCheckBox : ContentView
{
private readonly BoxView checkBox;
private readonly Frame frame;

public static readonly BindableProperty IsCheckedProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsChecked), typeof(bool), typeof(DinitCheckBox), false, propertyChanged: OnIsCheckedChanged);

public bool IsChecked
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(IsCheckedProperty);
    set => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, value);
}

public DinitCheckBox()
{
    checkBox = new BoxView
    {
        Color = Color.FromArgb("FFFFFFFF"),
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center
    };

    checkBox.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
    {
        Command = new Command(() => SetValue(IsCheckedProperty, !IsChecked))
    });

    frame = new Frame
    {
        WidthRequest = 20,
        HeightRequest = 20,
        CornerRadius = 2,
        BorderColor = Color.FromArgb("FF02A3A4"),
        Content = checkBox,
        Padding = 2
    };

    Content = frame;
}

private static void OnIsCheckedChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var checkBox = (DinitCheckBox)bindable;
    checkBox.checkBox.Color = (bool)newValue ? Color.FromArgb("FF02A3A4") : Color.FromArgb("FFFFFFFF");
}
```

}